Is there a meta site to ask questions regarding life as an IT professional, other than technology?
Here is sample of the type of questions I am referring to
"As IT professionals, we are told that we constantly need to keep learning and upgrading ourselves with whatever new comes out there. Easier said than done. We need to keep purchasing those thick books that are relatively expensive as compared to other genres of books. We are expected to be like a super sponge absorbing those books in quick time and then apply those things at the production level. We need to soak tons of knowledge and retain them for long. I am curious to know how do ace professionals handle all this?"

Note that we are told remarks often needs further refinement. If it's my employer tells me then the Workplace.SE suggestion is great. If it's book authors tell me I need to buy their books or random internet people want me to read more, then, well... Ignore them. There are always evangelists that want you to follow the new thing, but if you've stuck with COBOL throughout the years you've still got great job prospects.

The example question seems very broad, but if you narrow it down to "is it expected to buy expensive books out of pocket and study them while doing your regular job" then it may be on-topic for Workplace.SE.
If you frame it as "how do I talk to my boss that I can't do this/don't want to do this/need more time" then it may be on-topic for Interpersonal.SE.
For asking "it is good practise to always try using the newest frameworks" or "why do programmers switch frameworks so often" Software Engineering.SE may be an option.

The Chat, and in your case the StackOverflow Chat, is probably the best place to ask discussion types of questions.

On StackOverflow there is even a specific feature for "discussion types of questions" called discussions, but it's not recommended at the moment because it's wildly overrun by spam without effective built-in mechanisms to combat it unfortunately.
